# Can Samba be use for two types of servers at the same time?

Tags: 14.04, samba, samba4

I am currently setting up a server that use samba to act as a domain controller. In the meantime, I am planning to have a file server on the same machine. Will I able to use Samba as a file server too?

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes using the same machine as a domaincontroller and fileserver works. You set up samba as a dc and create your shares.